# How to set NetworkManager interface priority

Tags: ubuntu, networking, routes, default

I currently have two interfaces wlan0 and eth0

Network manager automatically creates a bunch of default gateways for eth0, as well as a dns resolution route too, all for eth0.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         mediabadger.loc 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         BThomehub.home  0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 wlan0
google-public-d mediabadger.loc 255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.101.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
mediabadger.loc *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
```

I would however like to specify which interface should have priority and therefore be the only default gateway.

I am editing `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired connection 1` directly through some code

So would like to know what setting to use, I have tried, the following without success:

```
[ipv4]
method=manual
dns=8.8.8.8
dns-search=local
addresses1=192.168.101.1;24;0.0.0.0;
never-default=true
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On investigation the issue is that connman was implemented. Disabling connman, or adding the following line to /etc/connman.conf resolves.

```
NetworkInterfaceBlacklist=*
```